# AWS Access ID sent to S3 differ from the one I specify in Node AWS-SDK

Tags: node.js, express, aws-sdk

I have an S3 bucket that I want to upload a file to from my Node backend. The upload fails become of a 403 error with the following message:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAI5L2C5CJPGACBIOA</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>A1BF9779D5888ADD</RequestId>
```

**Here's the code in rest api:**

```
  AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
  AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'AKIAIPMGLJ7BHQLGM3JA';
  AWS.config.secretAccessKey = '<None of your business>';

  var bucketName = "daniel-videostore"
  var s3bucket = new AWS.S3();

  var s3_params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 60, // expire after 60 mins
        ContentType: file.type,
        ACL: 'public-read',
    };

  s3bucket.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      console.log("Server Error occurred")
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      var return_data = {
        requestUrl : data,
        imageUrl: 'https://'+ bucketName +'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+ fileName
      };
      res.json( generalResponse( return_data ) );
    }
  });
```

As you can see the access id in response differs from the one that I specify in the sdk parameter. The one in resopnse is **AKIAI5L2C5CJPGACBIOA** while the one that I specify is shown in the code above. In fact, I don't recognize that access id in the resopnse. Could this be the problem that I'm getting the 403 error? Or is the ID switch normal from request and response? If so, what could be causing the Access ID error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Javascript SDK, I do not see the [options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html) for accessKeyId and secretAccessKey in the AWS.config object.

There is a credentials object.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', sessionToken = null));
```

The SDK's will look in four places for credentials. I'm assuming your default access key in your credentials file is **AKIAI5L2C5CJPGACBIOA**

1. Statics vars, ie how you're doing it
2. Env vars , export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ...
3. Credentials files, ~/.aws/credentials
4. [IAM instance profile for ec2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html)

Comment: Checking step three fixed the problem. It was a wrong key. Thanks.